# How can i remove /index in URL in routing in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, routes

I want to remove `/index` in URL.

I have already tried the following in routes.php file :

```
 Router::connect('/Home/:index', array('controller' => 'Homes'));
```

and :

```
 Router::connect('/Home/', array('controller' => 'Homes','action'=>'index'));
```

Comment: search about htaccess and cakephp

Comment: My root .htaccess file is :<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule> My app.htaccess file is                            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>My webroot .htaccess file is                      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @user2742023 are you entering URL directly or coming from any link?

Comment: I am entering it directly and when i am routing back to home page from some other page, it is showing me the /index in URL.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Router::connect('/Home', array('controller' => 'Homes','action'=>'index'));
```

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working it is still showing me /index in my URL.

Comment: what happen if you enter url like : domain.com/Home ?

Comment: It takes me to home page.

Comment: with or without index in url?

Comment: without index in URL.

Comment: So your problem solved,right? as you dont want to display index in URL

Comment: NO, because when i am routing back from other page, it shows me index in my URL. It is not showing me the index when i am directly entering the URL.

Comment: So please can you post your code how you have dispalyed that link,post you code

Comment: Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'index'));Router::connect('/homes', array('controller' => 'homes','action'=>'index')); This code is in routes.php.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for create link

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(__('YOUR_TEXT'),array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'index',array('class' => "", 'id' => ""));
?>
```

If you are creating link with this code then if is there any change made in routes then cakephp will update link according to that

Comment: on that page where you have displayed home link

Comment: this is the code i have used for displaying the link                    <li class="menulist">
   <?php  echo $this->Html->link($menu['Menu']['name'],array('controller' => $menu['Menu']['control'],
       'action' => $menu['Menu']['action'],$menu['Menu']['action_id'],
       'admin' => false,'plugin' => false),array('class'=>'menu'.$menu['Menu']['id']));?>                              
</li>                   The action_id is specified because i have one menu called products which has certain subcategories.

Comment: I have solve this problem. I was missing one field in database when i was displaying the link. Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: That's grate...n happy to help :)